# Python: Why still list elements are not disappeared after using procedure?

Tags: python, list

I define this function to do: [1,2,3] --> [2,3,1]

```
def shift_to_left(p):
    p.append(p[0])
    return p[1:]
```

When I check like this, results are ok:

```
p1 = [1,2,3]
print p1
p1 = shift_to_left(p1)
print p1
```

---

```
The result:
[1, 2, 3]
[2, 3, 1]
```

However, when I introduce another list and concatenate as I go the result is different:

```
ss = []
p1 = [1,2,3]
ss.append(p1)
p1 = shift_to_left(p1)
ss.append(p1)

print ss
```

---

```
The result
[[1, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]

But I want: 
[1,2,3]
[2,3,1]
```

why is it happening?

Thanks very much,

Comment: `return p[1:]` doesn't modify the original list.

Comment: Others have explained what is going on in a number of ways, so I will just mention the simplest correct implementation of your function: `return p[1:] + [p[0]]`

Comment: Examine the ids: print `id(p1)` before and after your calls, and the ids of the contents of `ss`.

Comment: Thanks very much guys, it is my first time to post questions. I am really impressed with answers and dynamic community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, most arguments are taken by reference.

Your function, `shift_to_left`, actually mutates its argument (through the use of append), but then returns a slice (which is a shallow copy of the list).

When you replace your original variable with the output of `shift_to_left`, this behaviour is hidden:

```
In [1]: def shift_to_left(p):
   ...:     p.append(p[0])
   ...:     return p[1:]
   ...: 

In [2]: xs = [1, 2, 3]

In [3]: xs = shift_to_left(xs)

In [4]: xs
Out[4]: [2, 3, 1]
```

But if we instead assign the result into a *new* variable, we can see that the original list has indeed been changed:

```
In [5]: ys = shift_to_left(xs)

In [6]: ys
Out[6]: [3, 1, 2]

In [7]: xs
Out[7]: [2, 3, 1, 2]
```

Our result, `ys`, is the slice of `xs` from the second element onwards.  That's what you expected.

But `xs` itself has *also* been changed by the call to `append`: it's now one element longer than before.
This is what you're experiencing in your second example.

---

If you do *not* want this behaviour, one way of avoiding it is by passing a copy of your list to `shift_to_left`:

```
In [8]: zs = shift_to_left(ys[:])

In [9]: zs
Out[9]: [1, 2, 3]

In [10]: ys
Out[10]: [3, 1, 2]
```

Here, you can see that the original list `ys` has not been modified, as `shift_to_left` was given a copy of it, not the object itself.  (This is still passing by reference, of course; it's just not a reference to `ys`).

---

Alternatively, and probably more reasonably, you could change `shift_to_left` itself, so that it does not modify its arguments:

```
def shift_to_left(xs):
    return xs[1:] + xs[0]  # build a new list in the return statement
```

The big problem with both these approaches is that they create lots of copies of lists, which can be incredibly slow (and use a lot of memory) when the lists are large.

---

Of course, as @Marcin points out, if this is more than an academic exercise, you should probably use one of the built-in data structures such as `deque`.

Comment: "In Python, most arguments are taken by reference" is not correct. In Python, all arguments are passed by assignment (or by object, if you will). See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference for explanations.

Comment: @KirkStrauser Unless I'm misunderstanding that post, it's saying that passing by assignment *is* by reference for mutable types (ie, for most of them).

Comment: The biggest thing to remember is that you're passing in the object that the variable points to, not the variable itself. It's a subtle but important difference.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to shift/rotate elements in a list, I think better would be to use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#deque-objects), rather than reinvent the wheel. For example:

```
from collections import deque
d = deque([1,2,3])
d.rotate(-1)
print(d) 
#[2, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Solves the problem but doesn't answer the question ("why") :) Meh, +1 anyway.

Comment: Although I agree, the question concerns itself with "why". Questions like these are very commonly used in university exams. Hence, having a solid understanding of why as opposed to alternatives is very important, especially in this case especially.

Comment: @Amadan  YOu right, I think other anwsers, answer the OP question pretty well. But using deque is probably faster, easier, less prone to errors, and generally more recommended way for what OP is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

If you run your code [here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html), you can notice that `ss` remains pointing to the original (mutated in your shift function because of `p.append(p[0])`) copy of `p1`, where as `p1` points to a knew list all together when it gets reassigned, resulting in the behavior. (Step 10 out of 11)

[image: p is mutated]

(`p` becomes mutated, and `ss[0] = p`)

[image: p1 gets assigned to a new list altogether]

(`p1` gets assigned to a new list altogether, which is latter appended to `ss`)

Comment: That's a pretty sweet educational tool.

Comment: @Amadan: This thing has saved my life sooo many times. Especially with pointer related stuff like this. I am so grateful for the person who made this.

Answer (score 1):

> why is it happening?

`return p[1:]` is "non-destructive": it creates a new list. However, `p.append(p[0])` is "destructive": it changes `p` itself.

First you append `p1` to `ss`. This makes `[[1, 2, 3]]`, where `[1, 2, 3]` is `p1`.

Then you do your `shift_to_left`, which changes `p1` to `[1, 2, 3, 1]` and returns `[2, 3, 1]`. Because `p1` is contained in `ss`, your `ss` becomes `[[1, 2, 3, 1]]`, and then you append the new `p1` to form `[[1, 2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]`.

A better implementation would be purely non-destructive:

```
def shift_to_left(p):
    return p[1:] + [p[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  p1 = [1,2,3]
  p1 = shift_to_left(p1)
  ss = []
  ss.extend(p1)

  print ss
```

That prints `[2, 3, 1]`. Use `extend()` instead because `append()` will create an array in an array. Also you had an extra call to `ss.append(p1)`.

Comment: He *wants* an array in an array, the desired solution (as badly-formatted-but-still-stated) is `[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 1]]`.